# Как получить физический адрес структуры в C#

Tags: c#, dll, memory, memory-management

Добрый день.

Необходимо во внешнюю библиотеку передать указатель на структуру IntPtr lpCmdData:

```
[DllImport("xxx.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr Start(IntPtr hService, uint dwCommand, IntPtr lpCmdData, uint dwTimeOut, ref _wfs_result lppResult);
```

Код самой структуры следующий:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct my_struct
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public ushort a;
        [FieldOffset(2)] public ushort b; 
        [FieldOffset(4)] public uint c;  
        [FieldOffset(8)] public bool d;
        [FieldOffset(9)] public IntPtr e; 
    };
```

Получение указателя на структуру делают через Marshal.StructureToPtr:

```
 int iSizeOfStruct = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(my_struct));
 IntPtr ptrDispense = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(iSizeOfStruct);
 Marshal.StructureToPtr(Struct1, ptrDispense, true);
```

Указатель получаю, когда передаю его в DLL, то получаю ошибку что указатель не верный.. Перегуглив два дня прихожу к выводу, что полученный адрес структуры доступен только в рамках .NET следовательно это не физический адрес памяти, а логический адрес. Вопрос возможно ли получить реальный физический адрес памяти который будет доступен вне приложения на .NET? Или можно создать структуру вне защищенной области?

P.S.
ковыряясь с кодом, заметил следующее, когда DLL возвращает мне указатель на память то он состоит из 10 чисел - пример 1255246569. Когда получают указатель в .NET он состоит из 7 чисел - 1542952

Comment: Последнее не понятно, т.к. 1. выравнивание памяти идёт стандартно по границам 4 байт, т.е. адрес должен быть кратен числу 4. И 2 AllocHGlobal равносильно GlobalAlloc, должно давать верный адрес.

Comment: да мне тоже не понятно... Когда одна из функций возвращает указатель  он десятизначный и структуру я спокойно считывают по указателю структуру. Но когда создаю указатель на собственную структуру он семизначный... Дополнительно я пишу на .NET2.0 под winxp

Answer (score 1):

Преобразование туда на вашем примере

```
my_struct cmddata = new cmddata();
//public static extern IntPtr Start(IntPtr hService, uint dwCommand, IntPtr   lpCmdData, uint dwTimeOut, ref _wfs_result lppResult);
Start(hService, dwCommand, Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArr‌​ayElement(cmddata,0), Timeout, lppResult);
```

Преобразование назад

```
IntPtr data = ...;
my_struct r =   (my_struct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(data, typeof(bootrec));
```

Comment: Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArr‌​ayElement требует первый параметр типа System.Array, что не соответствует моей структуре